# Rewrite from http to https with .htaccess doesnt work on strato.de

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a ssl-encrypted website and I want to transmit the users from my startpage from https to http, because of my banner ads. My problem is, that the rewriting with **.htaccess** doesn't work on strato.de. I tried the following code without success.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I also changed it a lot of times and the strato-support hasn't a solution too. They told me, that this is not possible. Does anyone had the similar problem `@ strato.de` or knows an approach?

Comment: Does your ad provider not support https? Who or what is Strato - is that your shared web host?

Comment: You should probably inquire with Strato whether they support .htaccess files and rewrite rules or if you have to do anything special to get them to work.

Comment: No, my ad provider doesnt support https :-( Do you know any ad provider who does it?

Sry, strato is my website provider (germany).

Strato support told me, that they cant solve my problem and i should ask in programmer-communities..

Answer (score 0):

> I want to transmit the users from my startpage from https to http,

If you want to target only start page then use this rule as very first rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not? If you get 500 errors then post your `VirtualHost` config for SSL

Comment: My .htaccess unfortunately is enabled, my provider confirmed it.
Where or how do I find the virtualhost config for ssl?

Comment: You need to get it from the same provider. Also did you run this 500 error test as I commented above?

Comment: ok, I ordered it from my provider, thinking I´ll get it tommorow. Yes, I did run your 500 error-test ;-)
Thank you so far, time for bed in germany